# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Send notification to specific user using cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have trigger function which activated when new comments are created inside  posts.
I want to send push notification to the device of author of the "post".

```
exports.notificationComments = functions.firestore
  .document("comments/{commentId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newData = snap.data();

    // newData.postAuthorId - post author firebase user id

    // how to send push notification to the post author?


  });
```

As I know we can use FCM-tokens which we can generate on users device and then send to the firebase database, store it there somewhere. And then from the trigger function read this FCM-token and send push notification to this token.

But can we get the FCM-token from firebase user id inside cloud functions? Or we need to send it from the device and store it every time user logins? 
I misunderstood something?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you already have the user id (which I assume is what you're using as the key to get the corresponding token), then your desired behavior should be possible.

Comment: You should query the database inside the function to get the token for the user.  It's no more complicated than that.

Comment: @DougStevenson but how can I get FCMtoken for the user inside the function?

Comment: Can I get device FCM registration token when I only have firebase user_id?